# Package android.os. does not exist Libgdx Netbeans

Tags: java, android, netbeans, libgdx

When trying to create an android libgdx application in the default imports is `import android.os.Bundle;` and netbeans says it can't find any package named `android.os`. Why does this happen and how could I get it to work?

```
package com.mygdx.game.android;

import android.os.Bundle;

import com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidApplication;
import com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidApplicationConfiguration;
import com.mygdx.game.MyGdxGame;

public class AndroidLauncher extends AndroidApplication {
    protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        AndroidApplicationConfiguration config = new AndroidApplicationConfiguration();
        initialize(new MyGdxGame(), config);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

It probably has to do with the gradle configuration setup you have. You'd probably be better off using either Android Studio or Eclipse. You'll find a lot more libgdx support for those IDEs. I'd recommend installing Android Studio and importing your project by opening the gradle config file in Android Studio.

Android Studio is made for Gradle.